# To check $(0,1)$ is open in $(0,1] $ or not

Tags: metric-spaces

We know $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Please explain if $(0,1)$ is open in $(0,1]$ or not.

How to do that?

Comment: use definitions: what is an open set in the (usual) metric topology of $\mathbb R$? Can you apply the definition to $(0,1]$, if you include $1$ on the right?

Comment: Subspace topology is defined as an intersection of the given subset with all open sets in the original set. Since $\left( {0,1} \right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, the answer becomes obvious

Answer (score 3):

When you have $X$ a subspace of a topological space $Y$, the open sets of $X$ are by definition the sets of the form $U \cap X$, where $U$ is open in $Y$. Take $X = [0,1]$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$. You should conclude easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use subspace topology. $$(0,1)=(0,1)\cap(0,1]$$

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged as metric-spaces, I'll assume you don't know about topology.

Remember, a set $A$ in a metric space is *open* if, for all $x \in A$, there's some open ball $x \in \{y : d(x,y) < r\} \subset A$. So pick $x \in (0,1)$, and then find a ball small enough around $x$ that's contained in $(0,1)$...